# vspace attribute applied to only one image not to both

Tags: css

I want only one image to have 20px margin on top and bottom. However for some reasons, it applies to both images. Is it possible to apply vspace attribute only to one image without affecting the image next to it ?

`<p>This is a sample text. This is a sample text</p>` 
       
     `<img src="images/cloudy.png" hspace="20" align="middle" alt="Cloud" />`
    
     `<img src="images/house.png" hspace="20" vspace="20" align="middle" alt="House" />`
  
  `<p>This is a sample text. This is a sample text</p>`

Here is how it looks and if you see both images have the same 20px margin on top and bottom 
[image]

Comment: can someone fix given code to make it visible please ?

Comment: It would be good if you can give us some code to look at...

Comment: I did but don't see it here ... can you tell me how to fix it ?

Comment: To show code in a question you should indent with four spaces before each code segment.

Comment: It appears to me that it's only applying space to the second image. Can you show us something more, maybe a screen shot of what the problem is that you're seeing?

Comment: bobdye beat me to it, the vspace isn't the problem, it's the align=middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better off using CSS.

But, given what you have, when you use:

```
vspace="20"
```

on one of the images, then it pushes the surrounding paragraphs away vertically.

Then the:

```
align="middle"
```

aligns both divs in the middle.

If you look at the images in Developer Tools, you can see that the first image has no vertical spacing.